# Vertical Middle overlay on top of img of undefined height, possible?

Tags: html, css

I've tried for past day to get this working, I had it working first in chrome with css tricks' `block:before` method but then I noticed it didn't work in firefox.

I went back to try the table method, but it didn't work with 100% height.

Essentially I have some masonry bricks with a title I want to position in the middle of each brick.

**Edit: I want to position the `<p>` tag to the middle of the image, the images are all of unknown height but a width of 200px.**

```
<div class="item">
<p><?php the_title(); ?></p>
<img src="<?php echo $url; ?>"  />
</div>
```

**Edit: I'd like text to appear in the middle of the Overlay element. The `<p>` tag's height is 1.5em and can be of any length, and should be dealt with by overflow auto. The overlay element is positioned absolute over the img, the img can be of any height but 200px width.**

```
<div class="item>
<div class="overlay" style="overflow:hidden; height:100%; width:100%; position:absolute;">
<p>the title</p>
</div>
<img src="<?php echo $url; ?>"  />
</div>
```

Help appreciated.

Comment: But how are those two blocks provided are related to each other?

Comment: Okay, ignore the first block.

Comment: What do you want to position in the middle of the image (vertically and horizontally)? The `<p>` element?

Comment: So, you mean the height of the div would be dependant on the img height inside, and you want that "p" to be placed over the image and centered vertically?

Comment: And also, does the height of "p" have definite height?

Comment: So, what's about the 'p' height? Is it defined or can be flexible?

Comment: @Agat The p height is 1.5em and can be of any length.

Comment: Actually, there is a great explanation of different forms of vertical alignment here: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/09/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/ Please, have a fast scan and let me know if you would need more assistance on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say this is your example markup:

```
<div class="item">
    <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>
    <img src="<?php echo $url; ?>" />
</div>
```

For a **pure CSS solution**, we can position the `<p>` element absolutely within the parent container `.item`. This is made under the assumption that the `.item` element has a defined width, but if you are using jQuery masonry (as in your question) then the width is typically predefined anyway.

The trick is to use position the `<p>` element in the center with top and left of 50%, and then offsetting the element by half of its own dimensions with CSS3 transform:

```
.item {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
}
.item > p {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.item > img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/e3pFy/3/

---

The drawbacks of this pure CSS solution is that it requires vendor prefixes, and that older browsers (such as IE8) are not supported. Should you want to ensure that it also works in older browsers, a JS-based solution would be useful. In this case, I have chosen to use jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $(".item > p").each(function() {
        $(this).css({
            "margin-left": $(this).outerWidth() * -0.5,
            "margin-top": $(this).outerHeight() * -0.5
        });
    });
});
```

So instead of translating the element to the top and to the left by negative of half its own dimension, we will use negative top and left margins instead, calculated as the half of the element's own dimension, too.

http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/e3pFy/4/

The major drawback with this method is that you will have to listen to various events that can possibly change the layout of the page, such as viewport resizing events and etc, which I find cumbersome and bloated.

Comment: Uhh, this doesn't work, I just looked at your fiddle and the title is still in the top left?

Comment: I also tried that method as I'm using it elsewhere to position and image, but I haven't been able to replicate it with the `<p>` tag.

Comment: That's really not working as even if the 'p' element is stretched vertically, it's text is still vertically aligned to top.

Comment: Sorry, it was an outdated fiddle. Let me fix that link.

Comment: @KyleJoseph Fixed the fiddle. Sorry about that.

Comment: @agat Fixed for now. For some reason I copied the wrong CSS from an outdated fiddle.

Comment: I notice you used transform, what versions of IE with this work with?

Comment: It works on IE9 with the `-ms-` vendor prefix, and from IE10 and above no vendor prefixing is required http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d

Comment: @Terry Very much appreciated.

Comment: @KyleJoseph Just updated my answer to include a JS-based solution, in case you would want to support older browser with no CSS3 2D transform support :)

Comment: Superstar :) much love.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, if you just have you 'p' element with fixed size, then you can easily do the following:

```
.item
{
    width:300px;
    position:relative;
}
p
{
    position:absolute;
    height:1.5em;
    margin-top:-.75em;
    top:50%;
}
```

(But you also can experiment with any example provided [here](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/09/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/) dependently on the layout you use or might use in future)

Comment: If I was every to change the font size though I would have to alter this code so it's not ideal really. Thanks.

Comment: Well, sure. That's the simpliest (and supported with a variety of old browsers) approach.